# string abbreviation creating dublicates

Tags: r

I'm trying to use `abbreviate` to come up with short unique abbreviations but its returning some unexpected values. If I run:

```
abbreviate(c('moscowcity', 'ms'), minlength = 2)
moscowcity         ms 
    "msc"       "ms"
```

it returns "mscw" instead of a simpler two-letter abbreviation such as "mo" or "mc" or "mt" or "my"

If I change to `strict = TRUE` it returns duplicates.

Is there any way to get both as two letter abbreviations that are also unique?

Comment: You can change the `minlength`.  `minlength` takes an integer value `abbreviate(c('moscowcity', 'ms'), minlength = 2)
moscowcity         ms 
     "msc"       "ms"`

Comment: `minlength` does not change the behavior. It still returns >2 length abbreviations

Comment: corrected the minlength argument. My question is more why doesn't `abbreviate` choose a different 2 letter combination with the other available letters in "moscowcity"

Comment: It is only because it doesn't crosscheck with other elements provided in the vector

Comment: is there a way for it crosschek? Or maybe another abbreviating function?

Comment: You can have a wrapper to do the crosscheck which calls the `abbreviate`

Comment: one issue with the word is that there is no delimiter in `moscowcity`

Answer (score 1):

If we change the `minlength` and wrap with `make.unique`, it would prevent the duplicates

```
make.unique(abbreviate(c('moscowcity', 'ms'), minlength = 2, strict = TRUE))
#[1] "ms"   "ms.1"
```

Here, the `abbreviate` is applied on each of the elements separately and it is not doing any crosschecks whether it already allocated same abbreviation previously

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question

> Is there any way to get both as two letter abbreviations that are also unique?

is: No, at least not with base `R` `abbreviate`

From `?abbreviate` (emphasis is mine)**:

> The default algorithm (method = "left.kept") used is similar to that of S. For a single string it works as follows. First spaces at the ends of the string are stripped. Then (if necessary) any other spaces are stripped. Next, lower case vowels are removed followed by lower case consonants. Finally if the abbreviation is still longer than minlength upper case letters and symbols are stripped.
>
> **Characters are always stripped from the end of the strings first**. If an element of names.arg contains more than one word (words are separated by spaces) then at least one letter from each word will be retained.

As I understand it, this means that you would **never** get a string like `mc` from `moscowcity` because the `c` will aready be stripped away when the algorythm tries `ms` (which then is flagged as not unique and the last unique value is used -> `msc`

## Edit:

**But**:
Because of the 'multiple word rule'

```
abbreviate(c("moscow city", "ms"), minlength = 2)
```

Returns:

```
moscow city          ms 
       "mc"        "ms"
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> The default algorithm (method = "left.kept") used is similar to that
>   of S. For a single string it works as follows. First spaces at the
>   ends of the string are stripped. Then (if necessary) any other spaces
>   are stripped. Next, lower case vowels are removed followed by lower
>   case consonants.

In other words, the algorithm starts by removing vowels (thus precluding `mo`), then consonants, stopping once a duplicate is created. To achieve what you're suggesting, which is a very complicated thing to do (look into the history of US postal state name abbreviations!), you'll have to create your own algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through the answers it looks like `abbreviate` wasn't really built for what I wanted. Taking @akrun's suggestion I wrote a wrapper function to create unique abbreviations.

**Improvements welcome!!**

```
btrAbbreviate = function(x, maxlen) {


  x = tolower(x)

  res = abbreviate(x, minlength = maxlen, strict = TRUE)
  dups = res[duplicated(res)]
  dupsChk = length(dups)

  while (dupsChk != 0) {
    firstChar = stringr::str_sub(names(dups), 1, 1)

    shfl = stringi::stri_rand_shuffle(substring(names(dups), 2))
    shfl = paste0(firstChar, shfl)

    out = stringr::str_sub(shfl, 1, 2)
    names(out) = names(dups)

    res[names(out)] = out

    dups = res[duplicated(res)]
    dupsChk = length(dups)
  }

  return(res)
}

x = state.name
btrAbbreviate(x, maxlen = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

minlength is supposed to be an integer, not a boolean. minlength defaults to 4, and you have set it to TRUE. Thus, minlength is telling it to always have at least 4 characters. You would need to do minlength=2 instead.

(edit: the original question had minlength=TRUE but has been changed)

https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/abbreviate.html